# Probability Distribution Function Problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_n$ represent data from a continuous distribution $F$. The empirical distribution function $F_e$ of these data is defined as $F_e(x) = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}(Y_i \leq x)}{n}$ where $\mathbf{1}(z) = 1$ if the predicate $z$ is true and 0 otherwise. Now define $D = \textrm{max}_x | F_e(x)-F(x) |$. Also define $E = \textrm{max}_{0 \leq y \leq 1} \Big|\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}(U_i \leq y)}{n} - y \Big|$ where $U_1, U_2, ..., U_n$ represent data from a $[0,1]$ uniform distribution. Now prove that $P(E \geq d) = P(D \geq d)$.

I have a very intuitive feel of this. I am not able to show it mathematically.

Comment: Note that $F^{-1} (Y)$ is an uniform random variable. And F is monotonically increasing so is $F^{-1}$ and you can apply this function in the inequality with $Y_i \leq x $

Comment: That's when F is invertible. It is not necessarily invertible

Comment: True. You can always define the generalized inverse distribution function $F^{-1}(x) = inf \{x \in \mathcal D_Y F(z)\geq x \}$ since F is monotically increasing (not necessarily invertible indeed). and you can prove that $F^{-1}(Y)$ is uniform

Comment: Shouldn't $F(Y)$ be a uniform random variable?

Comment: You are right. Sorry about this. My point was that F(Y) being uniform helps you to prove that E and D have the same distribution.   I will post a rigorous answer. = )

Answer (score 0):

**Lemma**: *$U=F(Y)$ is a standard uniform r.v*

Let the generalized inverse distribution function: $\mathcal F^{-1}(x) = inf \{x \in  \mathbb R, F(z)\geq x \}$.

$\forall u\in \mathbb R, P(U\leq u) =  P(F(Y)\leq u) =  P(Y\leq \mathcal  F^{-1}(u)) = F(\mathcal F^{-1}(u)) = u \mathbb 1_{u\in[0,1] + \mathbb 1_{u>1} } \\$

Note: You can draw a graph to convince you that  $\forall u\in[0,1], F(\mathcal F^{-1}(u)) = u$ even when F is constant on some interval.

**Proof**: *$P(E \geq d) = P(D \geq d)$*

This equation is equivalent to say that E and D have the same distribution: $ E\overset{\mathcal D}= D$

Using our lemma:

$ \forall x \in \mathcal D_Y, F_e(x) = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}(Y_i \leq x)}{n} = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}(F(Y_i) \leq F(x))}{n} \overset{D}= \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}(U_i \leq F(x))}{n}$

Note also that
 $\forall u\in [0,1], \exists x\in  \mathbb R$ s.t $F(x) =u$.

Therefore for any function g: $\underset{u\in[0,1]}{max} (g(u)) =  \underset{x\in \mathbb R}{max} (g(F(x))) $

Using our two results consecutively:

$\underset{u\in[0,1]}{max} |\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}(U_i \leq u)}{n} - u|  = \underset{x\in \mathbb R}{max} |\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}(U_i \leq F(x))}{n}-F(x)| \overset{D}=  \underset{x\in \mathbb R}{max} |\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}(Y_i \leq x)}{n}-F(x)| $